# Ground plane for a buck boost regulator circuit

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, ground-plane

I have made this circuit using [TPS63031](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63030.pdf):

[image: SCH]

Here is the board file:

[image: BRD]

I have closely followed the layout recommendations given in the datasheet:

[image: datasheet]

Circuit is a little different because I am using fixed output version.

My question is: Should I make a ground plane on the bottom layer? If yes, should I make it in whole area or just same as that in top layer i.e. bottom half of the board?

Comment: I'd do the whole layer ground. But then the question becomes do you need that ground on the top too and can you get rid of that one trace on the underside... I think you can.

Comment: You have missed the vias below the chip. These aren't there for decoration but for dissipating heat to the opposite layer (and/or core).

Comment: @Janka - yeah you are right. I left them because there was no ground plane on the bottom side. If the verdict is to make a GND plane on bottom, then I will make those vias as well. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree with Trevor's advice. In his proposal the secondary high-current loop is crippled by introducing two vias in the switching pass, adding unwanted inductance. It also will introduce current spikes into ground plane, which also has negative effect on overall signal integrity. Follow the recommended layout, even if the feedback loop is somewhat inconvenient to route.

Regarding the ground, the recommended layout is self-contained and doesn't need ground plane. If there is the plane, the circuit should be grounded in one localized point, just as the recommended layout shows. This will eliminate possibility of high-current ripples going into ground plane.

ADDITION: If the design can afford the ground layer, and the feedback in bottom layer is a nuisance, I see no reason to extend ground pads nor to the right, nor to the left, and keep one ground, at the center. Then the feedback wire doesn't need to be in a different layer,

[image: suggested modification]

In this case all HF ripples will be confined to local loops, and DC returns will go to the common (center) point. This the way how all old modules (VRMs) were done, and I believe this is the best way to have the power clean.

Comment: The problem I see with the recommended layout is that the input/output ground wires will be on both sides, and significant HF current will flow in the pcb ground track, so the wires will have common mode noise voltage, perhaps act as antennas. I'm not sure how to fix this cleanly.

Comment: I do agree in principal the addition of the vias in the ground path does introduce a slight irritant in the loop, though for such a small loop I doubt it matters. Keeping/running the return trace from the two caps on the right to the right of C2 would correct that giving you a single point ground hook under U1.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the whole underside layer ground.

But then the question becomes do you need that ground on the top too. The answer is.. no not really.

If you break the top ground up, with appropriate vias to the ground plane, you can then get rid of that one long trace on the underside, and really tighten up the feedback line as a short trace between pins on U1.

Maybe something like this...

[image]

Comment: How about this: I make a full GND plane on bottom, make broken GND plane on top with short feedback line like you said? Will it be better? I want to keep top GND plane to help with heat dissipation. Another thought is that - Will a short trace for feedback be actually a good idea? OR should I take feedback after the caps to prevent any switching noise? I get it that trace inductance won't be that high to make much of a difference but I'd love to have an expert's opinion.

Comment: If heat is an issue add more vias under U1, the fact the underside is all one copper plane will help a lot. If need be open up the solder resist on the bottom in a checkerboard pattern so you can solder it to add heat sink surface. With these devices keeping that trace from output to cap  tops to feedback pin as short as possible is key... as long as it is short, order does not matter.